# How to add button at the end of each column in datatable in MVC 4?

Tags: jquery, database, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to this concept. I want to add a Button at the end of each column in a datatable.

I can do this in asp.net, but I do not have any idea in MVC 4.

Please advise me on this issue.

Code Below:

```
<table class="plans-table">    
    <thead>
        <tr>                        
            @foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                <th>(@col.ColumnName)</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
        <tr class="plans-row">
            @foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                <td>
                    @row[col.ColumnName]
                </td> 
            }
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How are you creating your datatable? If it's build from html, why not just add the button tag?

Comment: I have posted my code for datatable above. How can i add the button tag the end of each column. I am using a table for plans and pricing, so i need the customers to select any of the plans. How to add the button tag at the end of each column.? Please kindly advise me on that

Comment: I have did it. Thanks..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a button at the end of each row, like:

```
<table class="plans-table">    
    <thead>
        <tr>                        
            @foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                <th>(@col.ColumnName)</th>
            }
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
        <tr class="plans-row">
            @foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                <td>
                    @row[col.ColumnName]
                </td> 
            }
            <td><input type="button" value="Click Me!" name="rowButton"/></td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As MVC differs from `ASP.NET` in structure, you will note that this is a normal html button.  As such, you will need to use javascript to perform postbacks or other operations.